# WSO2 IOT : Failed to activate org.wso2.carbon.appmgt.mdm

Tags: wso2-iot

When I run WSO2 Iot, I have an error from the beginning :

```
[IoT-Core] ERROR - MDMComponent Failed to activate org.wso2.carbon.appmgt.mdm.restconnector.internal.MDMComponent : java.lang.NullPointerException: username
```

I made no changes to the files

Thank for your help

Tof

Comment: What is the IoT server version?

Comment: I use the WSO iot version of Jenkins (V3.1.0): https://wso2.org/jenkins/job/product-iots__java8/org.wso2.iot$wso2iot-core/

The error occurs on version 3.1.0 - Distribution: # 313, # 314, # 315

Comment: Since 3.1.0 is still under development, it may be not stable. it's better to use 3.0.0 GA.

Comment: Thank Shasha, you are a link for wso2 iot 3.0.0 GA ?

Comment: http://wso2.com/products/iot-server/

Comment: Hello,
I am always looking for a solution for this error. Which one would have an answer?

Answer (score 0):

[WSO2 IoT 3.1.0](http://wso2.com/iot/) is released now, This issue is fixed in the latest pack.